# remove a url segment based on if there are X number of segments present

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me with a regular expression that would help me do this.

I have a url: `http://www.site.com/foo/bar`

when a user clicks on a link it will append it to the url making it look like this

```
http://www.site.com/foo/bar/link1
```

now for the tricky part, when a second link is clicked it keeps appending to the url like this

```
http://www.site.com/foo/bar/link1/link2
```

i would like for link2 to replace link1 making it `http://www.site.com/foo/bar/link2`

I want to note that the only reason links are appending like this are because I am using this expression to remove the `'#'` from the link and replacing it with `'/'`

```
location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/g, "/"))
```

without the # the browser will not know to replace the hash marks but its causing me issues with my current setup.

Otherwise the link will look like `http://www.site.com/foo/bar#link1` witch doesn't exist with my setup

I'm using `htaccess` to replace `page.php?type=foo&user=bar&page=link1` `http://www.site.com/foo/bar/link1`

so ya, my question is how to remove `/link1` with `/link2` BUT append link2 IF `/link1` isn't present

I want to keep the code as dynamic as possible since the link names could change.

EDIT:
My code

```
var newHash    = "",
        shref      = "",
        content    = '#content',
        $c         = $("#content"),
        $cw        = $("#content-wrapper");

    $(".menu-link, #my-account-link").live('click', function(){
        shref = $(this).attr("href").split("/");
        //window.location.hash = shref[5];
        //location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/g, "/"))
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        //console.log(window.location.hash);
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        /*if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
            location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/?#/g, "/"));
        }*/
        //TODO:: Find # replace with / then find first (or maybe 3rd/) and replace everything until the next / with ""
        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        console.log(newHash);
        if(newHash)
        {
            $cw.find(content).fadeOut(200, function() {
                $cw.load(newHash + " #content-wrapper", function() {
                    $c.fadeIn();
                });
            });
        }
    });
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex-based solution?

Comment: well no, but it was my idea that it was how it was suppose to be done...heh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newElement   = document.location.hash.replace('#', ''); // after hash
var pathElements = document.location.pathname.split('/');
var lastElement  = pathElements[pathElements.length - 1];
var endElements  = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3'];

// the final element not in list
if(endElements.indexOf(lastElement) === -1) {
  pathElements.push(newElement);
}
// replace last element
else {
  pathElements.pop();
  pathElements.push(newElement);
}

document.location.pathname = pathElements.join('/');
```

Comment: is there a problem with my solution?

Comment: no, was just curious that I have a hash change event going on to detect when the url changes to load in my content via ajax, will this solution still let me have the same ajax feel and look to my links